# Maximum call stack size exceeded | error al abrir un canvas desde jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un boton tipo href que llama a traves de la clase "openRightModal" a un evento que consulta la base de datos, funciona de maravilla solo 2 veces, si el usuario cierra y abre el offcanvas mas de dos veces entonces genera el error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` y se deshabilitan todos los botones, la manera en la que tengo dicho evento se conforma asi:

```
    // si el usuario hace click en el boton con la clase openRightModal se ejecuta el metodo OpenFormCanvas
    $("body").on("click", ".openRightModal", openFormCanvas);


// al mismo tiempo se ejecuta la consulta a un link que trae el formulario y lo inserta en el offcanvas
$("body").on("click", ".openRightModal", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const requestUrl = this.href;

    let redirectUrl = "";
    if (typeof $(this).data("redirect-url") !== "undefined") {
        redirectUrl = encodeURIComponent($(this).data("redirect-url"));
    }

    $.easyAjax({
        url: requestUrl,
        blockUI: true,
        container: RIGHT_MODAL,
        historyPush: !inModal,
        data: { redirectUrl: redirectUrl },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status == "success") {
                $(RIGHT_MODAL_CONTENT).html(response.html);
                $(RIGHT_MODAL_TITLE).html(response.title);
            }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            //console.log(request.responseText);
            if (request.status == 403) {
                $(RIGHT_MODAL_CONTENT).html(
                    '<div class="align-content-between d-flex justify-content-center mt-105 f-21">403 | Permission Denied</div>'
                );
            } else if (request.status == 404) {
                $(RIGHT_MODAL_CONTENT).html(
                    '<div class="align-content-between d-flex justify-content-center mt-105 f-21">404 | Not Found</div>'
                );
            } else if (request.status == 500) {
                $(RIGHT_MODAL_CONTENT).html(
                    '<div class="align-content-between d-flex justify-content-center mt-105 f-21">500 | Something Went Wrong</div>'
                );
            }
        },
    });
});
```

consulta la url e inserta la respuesta html en el siguiente offcanvas:

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-form"  id="offcanvasForm" aria-labelledby="offcanvasEndLabel">
    <div class="offcanvas-header" id="close-form-canvas-overlay">
        <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-form-close closeRightModal text-reset close-form-canvas"
            data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
            id="close-form-canvas"
            aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <section id="multiple-column-form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 id="offcanvasForm-title" class="card-title">Title</h4>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                            <div id="offcanvasForm-content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-1">Continue</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

dicho modal esta definido en la variable `RIGHT_MODAL` en la plantilla de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>
    const RIGHT_MODAL = '#offcanvasForm';
    const RIGHT_MODAL_CONTENT = '#offcanvasForm-content';
    const RIGHT_MODAL_TITLE = '#offcanvasForm-title';
</script>
```

cuando se da click en abrir este metodo: `$("body").on("click", ".openRightModal", openFormCanvas);` ejecuta la siguiente funcion que lo abre:

```
function openFormCanvas() {
    new bootstrap.Offcanvas(document.getElementById("offcanvasForm")).show();
}
```

y hay una mas que lo cierra y esta ligado al botton de cancel y de X del offcanvas:

```
function closeFormCanvas() {
    new bootstrap.Offcanvas(document.getElementById("offcanvasForm")).hide();
}
```

entiendo que el `error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` es por un bucle que se esta repitiendo indefinidamente, pero es que no encuentro en que zona esta siendo repetido y porque funciona solo 2 veces, espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar el error porque ya pase horas dandole vueltas a este asunto.

Comment: Con solo este código no he sido capaz de reproducir el comportamiento que dices. He agregado un botón para cerrar la ventana modal y puedo abrirla y cerrarla tantas veces como desee. Por otro lado, ¿no sería mejor abrir la ventana modal solo cuando te lleguen los datos que deseas mostrar en ella en vez de abrirla y cuando lleguen que aparezcan mágicamente? Edito: ¿tienes más manipuladores de eventos? ¿Se puede probar la página en línea en alguna URL? Creo que en tu pregunta falta el código que provoca el problema.

Comment: Por si fuera algún problema que haya sido resuelto en las últimas versiones de jQuery y Bootstrap o algún problema con una versión en específico, ¿podrías editar la pregunta y facilitar las versiones o las URLs exactas desde donde cargas las bibliotecas externas? Gracias.

Comment: Tras echar un nuevo vistazo a tu código y ver que lo único que había retirado de mi código para reproducir tu problema era la parte de `$.easyAjax` (no tengo ni idea de dónde has sacado esa función), creo que la recursión puede venir del HTML que inyectas al HTML allí. De modo que voto el cierre de la pregunta por no poder reproducir el problema y no aportar toda la información que se necesita para ello.

Comment: Para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Gracias.